# difficulties with a buffer that uses std vector as storage in a library and using this buffer inside another library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, stdvector

i have a class named IBuffer that uses std::vector as a storage of unsigned char data.
this class is part of my foundation library named core.lib.
responsibility of this class is writing data into buffer and reading from it.
ok
now i am using this class in another library for the purpose of serializing and deserializing messages received from network.

i am allways have problem with memory access violation reading location 0Xxxxxxx when i try to pushback new data in to std::vector.
as it is hard to write thousand lines of code here i put stack trace here i hope anyone help me to solve this problem.

```
        ntdll.dll!@RtlpLowFragHeapFree@8()  + 0x2c bytes    
    ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeap@12()  + 0x7e bytes   
    kernel32.dll!_HeapFree@12()  + 0x14 bytes   
    msvcr100d.dll!__free_base()  + 0x29 bytes   
    msvcr100d.dll!__free_dbg_nolock()  + 0x4ae bytes    
    msvcr100d.dll!__free_dbg()  + 0x50 bytes    
    msvcr100d.dll!operator delete()  + 0xb9 bytes   
>   ICore.dll!std::allocator<unsigned char>::deallocate(unsigned char * _Ptr=0x002c7810, unsigned int __formal=1)  Line 182 + 0x9 bytes C++
    ICore.dll!std::vector<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_Insert_n(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> > > _Where=221 'Ý', unsigned int _Count=2, const unsigned char & _Val='')  Line 1375    C++
    ICore.dll!std::vector<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> >::insert(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> > > _Where=221 'Ý', unsigned int _Count=1, const unsigned char & _Val='')  Line 1060   C++
    ICore.dll!Utils::IBuffer::WriteShort(unsigned short data=256)  Line 63 + 0x56 bytes C++
    ICore.dll!Serialization::IBufferWriter::writeUShort(unsigned short data=256)  Line 82   C++
    IRNet.dll!IRNetwork::IStunMessage::AcceptWriter(Serialization::IIWriter * writer=0x0040f080)  Line 340 + 0x2e bytes C++
    IRNet.dll!Serialization::IBufferWriter::WriteObject<IRNetwork::IStunMessage>(const Object::IObject * object=0x002cb5f0)  Line 105 + 0x17 bytes  C++
    IRNet.dll!IRNetwork::IStunMessage::Serialize(Object::SharedPtr<Utils::IBuffer> buffer={...})  Line 769  C++
    IRNet.dll!IRNetwork::IStun::SendUnReliably(IRNetwork::IStunMessage * message=0x002cb5f0)  Line 157  C++
    IRNet.dll!IRNetwork::IStun::SendBind()  Line 61 + 0xc bytes C++
    IRNet.dll!IRNetwork::IStun::Bind(unsigned int localfd=184)  Line 48 C++
    IRNet.dll!IRNetwork::INatContext::StunBind(unsigned int fd=184)  Line 52 + 0xc bytes    C++
    testDhcpv4.exe!TestStunAttribute::Start()  Line 48 + 0x24 bytes C++
    testDhcpv4.exe!wmain(int argc=1, wchar_t * * argv=0x002c71d8)  Line 69  C++
    testDhcpv4.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 552 + 0x19 bytes   C
    testDhcpv4.exe!wmainCRTStartup()  Line 371  C
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

**IBUffer.h**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ICoreConfig.h"
#include "ILMutex.hxx"
#include "ILock.hxx"
#include <vector>
using namespace IThreading;
using namespace std;
namespace Utils
{
/*
#ifdef EXP_STL
#    define DECLSPECIFIER __declspec(dllexport)
#    define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE
#else
#    define DECLSPECIFIER __declspec(dllimport)
#    define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE extern
#endif

    EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template class DECLSPECIFIER std::vector<unsigned char>;*/

    template class ICORE_API std::allocator<unsigned char>;
    template class ICORE_API std::vector<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> >;
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    typedef enum 
    {
        /*Begin Of Buffer*/
        BOB = 0,
        /*End Of Buffer*/
        EOB = 1,
        /*Unknown*/
        UNK = 2
    } BufferState_t;
    class ICORE_API IBuffer
    {
    public:
        IBuffer(void);
        IBuffer(IBuffer* newbuff);
        ~IBuffer(void);
        //Methods
        int Write(const void* data,size_t size);
        int Write(const void** data, size_t sz);
        int Write(size_t position , const void* data,size_t sz);
        int WriteShort(unsigned short data);
        int WriteShort(uint32_t position,unsigned short data);
        int WriteByte(unsigned char data);
        int WriteUInt(unsigned int data);
        int WriteUlong(unsigned long data);



        //************************************
        // Method:    ReadByte
        // FullName:  BufferPool::ReadByte
        // Access:    public 
        // Returns:   unsigned char
        // Qualifier:
        //Description: Read and return one byte of data by starting from begining of buffer
        //************************************
        unsigned char ReadByte();
        unsigned short ReadShort();
        unsigned int ReadUint32();
        unsigned long ReadUlong();
        unsigned char* Read(size_t sz);

        /** Converts a 16-bit value from host to TCP/IP network byte order (big-endian).
        * @param x The 16-bit (in host byte order) value to convert.
        * @retval @a x in TCP/IP network byte order.
        */
        unsigned short HostToNetworkByteOrder(unsigned short x);

        /* Memory alignment hack */
        //************************************
        // Method:    HostToNetworkByteOrder
        // FullName:  BufferPool::HostToNetworkByteOrder
        // Access:    public 
        // Returns:   unsigned short
        // Qualifier:
        // Parameter: const void * px
        // Description: This method used when we want to Pars existing buffer
        //************************************
        unsigned short HostToNetworkByteOrder(const void* px);

        unsigned short NetworkToHostByteOrder(const unsigned short x);

        /** Converts a 32-bit value from host to TCP/IP network byte order (big-endian).
        * @param x The 32-bit (in host byte order) value to convert.
        * @retval @a x in TCP/IP network byte order.
        */
        unsigned long HostToNetworkByteOrder(unsigned long x);

        /* Memory alignment hack */
        //************************************
        // Method:    HostToNetworkByteOrderUL
        // FullName:  BufferPool::HostToNetworkByteOrderUL
        // Access:    public 
        // Returns:   unsigned long
        // Qualifier:
        // Parameter: const void * px
        // Description: this method used when we want to pars existing buffer
        //************************************
        unsigned long HostToNetworkByteOrderUL(const void* px);
        //* parse unsigned int type to byte array as is
        vector<unsigned char> Uint32ToByteArray(unsigned int x);

        uint8_t* ToUInt8ptr();

        unsigned long NetworkToHostByteOrder(const unsigned long x);


/*      IBuffer operator =(const IBuffer &buf);*/
        IBuffer& operator =(IBuffer &Rhs);
        IBuffer& operator =(char* rhs);

        operator char*();
        operator void*();
        operator uint8_t*();

        //************************************
        // Method:    operator++
        // FullName:  BufferPool::operator++
        // Access:    public 
        // Returns:   BufferPool
        // Qualifier:
        // Description: This method increment dataPtr
        //              read one byte , increment dataPtr by one
        //              read short , increment dataPtr by two
        //              read unsigned int increment dataPtr by 4
        //              note : each read function set currPosion in suitable way
        //              we do this because of continuous buffer reading
        //************************************
        void operator ++();
        bool operator<(const IBuffer& buff)
        {
            return this->Size() < buff.Size() ? true : false;
        }

        bool operator==(const IBuffer& buff)
        {
            return this->buffer == buff.buffer;
        }
        //Properties
        bool IsEmpty();
        unsigned char* Value();

        /** Indicates whether we are on a Big Endian host or not.<br>
        * IMPORTANT: Before calling this function, you should initialize the network stack by using
        * @ref tnet_startup().
        * @retval @a true if the program is running on a Big Endian host and @a false otherwise.
        */
        bool IsBigEndian();
        inline unsigned char HI_Uint16(unsigned short x)
        {
            return (((x) >> 8) & 0xFF) ;
        }
        inline unsigned char LOW_Uint16(unsigned short x)
        {
            return ((x) & 0xFF);
        }
        size_t Size() const;
        void SetPtr();

        void CleanUp();

        void Move(int32_t count);
    private:
        inline int GetPosition()
        {
            return currPosition;
        }

        int SetPosition(int newpos);
    public:
        static class _Convert
        {
        public:
            static inline unsigned short ToUShort(const unsigned char* u8_ptr)
            {
                return (((unsigned short)(u8_ptr)[0]) | ((unsigned short)(u8_ptr)[1])<<8);
            }
            static inline unsigned int ToUint32(const unsigned char* u8_ptr)
            {
                return (((unsigned int)(u8_ptr)[3]) | ((unsigned int)(u8_ptr)[2])<<8 | ((unsigned int)(u8_ptr)[1])<<16 | ((unsigned int)(u8_ptr)[0])<<24);
            }

            static inline signed int ToInt32(const unsigned char* u8_ptr)
            {
                return (((signed int)(u8_ptr)[0]) | ((signed int)(u8_ptr)[1])<<8 | ((signed int)(u8_ptr)[2])<<16 | ((signed int)(u8_ptr)[3])<<24);
            }
        protected:

        private:
        } Convert;
        static BufferState_t bstate;
        Mutex mMutex;
    private:        
        vector<unsigned char> buffer;
        vector<unsigned char>::pointer dataPtr;
        int currPosition;
        bool ptrSet;
    };
}
```

**IBuffer.cpp**

```
    #include "StdAfx.h"
#include "IBufferPool.h"
#include <iostream>
namespace Utils
{

    IBuffer::IBuffer(void) 
        : currPosition(0), ptrSet(false) 
    {
        /*buffer.push_back('\0');*/
        SetPtr();
    }

    IBuffer::IBuffer( IBuffer* newbuff )
        :currPosition(0)
    {
    }

    IBuffer::~IBuffer(void)
    {
        if (GetPosition() != 0)
        {
            dataPtr = buffer.data();
        }

        buffer.clear();
        dataPtr = NULL;
        SetPosition(0);
        /*std::cout<<"Ibuffer Freed \n";*/
    }

    //************************************
    // Method:    WriteByte
    // FullName:  BufferPool::WriteByte
    // Access:    public 
    // Returns:   int
    // Qualifier:
    // Parameter: unsigned char data
    // Description: write data of type byte in to buffer
    //************************************
    int IBuffer::WriteByte(unsigned char data)
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        buffer.push_back(data);
        SetPtr();
        return 0;
    }

    //tested OK
    int IBuffer::WriteShort(unsigned short data)
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        unsigned char temp;
        //first we convert to network byte order
        /*unsigned short tmpData = HostToNetworkByteOrder(data);*/
        //lower byte

        temp = LOW_Uint16(/*tmpData*/data);
        //buffer.push_back(temp);          /// Access violation
        buffer.insert(buffer.end(),1,temp);
        temp = HI_Uint16(/*tmpData*/data);
        //buffer.push_back(temp);          /// Access violation
        buffer.insert(buffer.end(),1,temp);
        SetPtr();
        return 0;
    }

    int IBuffer::WriteShort( uint32_t position,unsigned short data )
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        vector<unsigned char>::pointer pt = buffer.data();
        pt+=position;

        *pt=LOW_Uint16(data);
        pt++;
        *pt=HI_Uint16(data);
        SetPtr();
        return 0;
    }

    int IBuffer::WriteUInt(unsigned int data)
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        //unsigned int and unsigned long both have 4 byte length except that unsigned long can accept floating point numbers

        vector<unsigned char> vt = Uint32ToByteArray(data);

        for each(const unsigned char &i in vt)
        {
            buffer.push_back(i);
        }
        SetPtr();
        return 0;
    }

    int IBuffer::WriteUlong( unsigned long data )
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        return WriteUInt(data);
    }

    vector<unsigned char> IBuffer::Uint32ToByteArray(unsigned int x)
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        vector<unsigned char> arrayOfByte(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            arrayOfByte[3 - i] = (x >> (i * 8));
        return arrayOfByte;
    }

    uint8_t* IBuffer::ToUInt8ptr()
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        uint8_t* u8arr = (uint8_t*)this->buffer.data();
        size_t sz = this->buffer.size();
        u8arr[sz] = '\0';
        return u8arr;
    }

    bool IBuffer::IsEmpty()
    {
        if(!buffer.size())
            return true;
        return false;
    }


    unsigned char* IBuffer::Value()
    {
        if(!dataPtr)
        {
            dataPtr = buffer.data();
        }
        return dataPtr;
    }


    unsigned short IBuffer::HostToNetworkByteOrder(unsigned short x)
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        if(IsBigEndian()){
            return x;
        }
        else{
            return ((((unsigned short)(x) & 0xff00) >> 8)       |
                (((unsigned short)(x) & 0x00ff) << 8));
        }
    }


    unsigned short IBuffer::HostToNetworkByteOrder(const void* px)
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        unsigned short y = IBuffer::Convert.ToUShort((const unsigned char*)px);//IRV_TO_UINT16((const unsigned char*)px);
        return HostToNetworkByteOrder(y);
    }


    unsigned long IBuffer::HostToNetworkByteOrder(unsigned long x)
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        if(IsBigEndian()){
            return x;
        }
        else{
            return ((((unsigned int)(x) & 0xff000000) >> 24)    | \
                (((unsigned int)(x) & 0x00ff0000) >> 8)     | \
                (((unsigned int)(x) & 0x0000ff00) << 8)     | \
                (((unsigned int)(x) & 0x000000ff) << 24));
        }
    }


    unsigned long IBuffer::HostToNetworkByteOrderUL(const void* px)
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        unsigned long y = IBuffer::Convert.ToUShort((const unsigned char*)px);
        return HostToNetworkByteOrder(y);
    }

    unsigned long IBuffer::NetworkToHostByteOrder(const unsigned long x)
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        if(IsBigEndian()){
            return x;
        }
        else{
            return ((((unsigned int)(x) & 0x000000ff) << 24)    | \
                (((unsigned int)(x) & 0x0000ff00) << 8) | \
                (((unsigned int)(x) & 0x00ff0000) >> 8)         | \
                (((unsigned int)(x) & 0xff000000) >> 24));
        }
    }

    unsigned short IBuffer::NetworkToHostByteOrder( const unsigned short x )
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        if(IsBigEndian()){
            return x;
        }
        else{
            return ((((unsigned short)(x) & 0x00ff) << 8)       |
                (((unsigned short)(x) & 0xff00) >> 8));
        }
    }

    bool IBuffer::IsBigEndian(){
        /* If LITTLE_ENDIAN or BIG_ENDIAN macros have been defined in config.h ==> use them
        * otherwise ==> dyn retrieve the endianness
        */
        short word = 0x4321;
#if LITTLE_ENDIAN
        return false;
#elif BIG_ENDIAN
        return true;
#else
        return ((*(signed char *)&word) != 0x21);
#endif
    }

/*
    IBuffer IBuffer::operator=( const IBuffer &buf )
    {
        IBuffer bf;
        bf.buffer = buf.buffer;
        return bf;
    }*/

    IBuffer& IBuffer::operator=(IBuffer& Rhs)
    {
        if (this != &Rhs)
        {
            if (this->dataPtr && this->Size()>0 && this->GetPosition()>0)
            {
                delete this;
            }
            buffer=Rhs.buffer;
            dataPtr = Rhs.dataPtr;
            currPosition = Rhs.GetPosition();
        }
        return *this;

    }

    IBuffer& IBuffer::operator=( char* rhs )
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        if (this->buffer.size() != 0)
        {
            this->buffer.clear();
        }
        if (this->currPosition !=0)
        {
            this->currPosition = 0;
        }
        this->Write(rhs,strlen(rhs));
        return * this;
    }

    //Move forward data pointer by one
    void IBuffer::operator++()
    {
        dataPtr++;
        SetPosition(1);
        //dataPtr+=GetPosition();
    }

    //************************************
    // Method:    ReadByte
    // FullName:  BufferPool::ReadByte
    // Access:    public 
    // Returns:   unsigned char
    // Qualifier:
    // Parameter: 
    // Description: read data of type byte and move forward data pointer
    //************************************
    unsigned char IBuffer::ReadByte()
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        unsigned char ret = (*(dataPtr));
        dataPtr++;
        SetPosition(1);
        return ret;
    }

    unsigned short IBuffer::ReadShort()
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        unsigned short ret=/*HostToNetworkByteOrder((unsigned char*)(dataPtr))*/IBuffer::Convert.ToUShort((unsigned char*)(dataPtr));
        dataPtr+=2;
        SetPosition(2);
        return ret;
    }

    unsigned int IBuffer::ReadUint32()
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        //I DON NOT KHNOW MUST CONVERT RECIEVED MESSAGE TO LITTLE ENDIAN OR NOT?
        unsigned int ui=/*HostToNetworkByteOrderUL((unsigned char*)(dataPtr))*/Convert.ToUint32((unsigned char*)(dataPtr));
        dataPtr+=4;
        SetPosition(4);
        return ui;
    }

    unsigned long IBuffer::ReadUlong()
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        return (unsigned long) ReadUint32();
    }

    unsigned char* IBuffer::Read(size_t sz)
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        //return a block of data
        unsigned char* tmp = new unsigned char;
        /*Lock lock(mMutex);*/
        for (int i = 1;i<=sz;i++)
        {
            tmp[i-1] = *dataPtr++;
        }
        //dataPtr +=sz;
        tmp[sz] = '\0';
        SetPosition(sz);
        return tmp;
    }

    IBuffer::operator char*()
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        char* ret = (char*)buffer.data();
        ret[buffer.size()] = '\0';
        return ret;
    }

    IBuffer::operator void*()
    {
        return (void*)buffer.data();
    }

    int IBuffer::Write(const void* data,size_t size )
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        unsigned char* udata = (unsigned char*)data;
        /*Lock lock(mMutex);*/
        for (size_t i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            buffer.push_back(*udata++);
        }
        SetPtr();
        return 0;
    }

    int IBuffer::Write( const void** data, size_t sz )
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        unsigned char* udata = (unsigned char*)data;
        /*Lock lock(mMutex);*/
        for (size_t i=0;i<sz;i++)
        {
            buffer.push_back(*udata++);
        }
        SetPtr();
        return 0;
    }

    int IBuffer::Write( size_t position , const void* data,size_t sz )
    {
        Lock lock(mMutex);
        unsigned char* udata = (unsigned char*)data;
        vector<unsigned char>::pointer pt = buffer.data();
        /*Lock lock(mMutex);*/
        pt+=position;
        for (size_t i=0;i<sz;i++)
        {
            *pt=(unsigned char)(*udata++);
            pt++;
        }
        SetPtr();
        return 0;
    }

    IBuffer::operator uint8_t*()
    {
        return (uint8_t*) buffer.data();
    }

    void IBuffer::CleanUp()
    {
        if (this->Size() > 0 && this->dataPtr)
        {
            this->buffer.clear();
            this->SetPosition(0);
            this->dataPtr = NULL;
        }
    }

    void IBuffer::SetPtr()
    {
        if (!IsEmpty() /*&& !ptrSet*/)
        {
            dataPtr=buffer.data();
            ptrSet=true;
            bstate = BOB;
        }       
    }

    size_t IBuffer::Size() const
    {
        return buffer.size();
    }

    int IBuffer::SetPosition( int newpos )
    {
        //if before read function take placed then current position must be updated to new position
        //our CURSOR move forward by newpos
        if (currPosition == 0)
        {
            currPosition = newpos;
        } 
        else
        {
            currPosition += newpos;
            if (this->Size() == currPosition)
            {
                bstate = EOB;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void IBuffer::Move( int32_t count )
    {
        SetPosition(count);
        dataPtr+=count;
    }

    BufferState_t IBuffer::bstate(BOB);
```

these 2 classes are not final.i only test to see is it possible to use vector as a buffer in this way i select or not.i think it is not good idea.

Edit:

> i change the implementation of Ibuffer by using HeapAlloc and
>   HeapRealloc but i got this exeption
>
> **Unhandled exception at 0x774a2913 (ntdll.dll) in testDhcpv4.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted.**

please help me.

with best wishes

Comment: There's way too much code here. You'll need to use a debugger to narrow it down.

Comment: by using debugger everything works fine.but out side of debugger application crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Too much code, but I spotted this

```
IBuffer::operator char*()
{
    Lock lock(mMutex);
    char* ret = (char*)buffer.data();
    ret[buffer.size()] = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

That is undefined behaviour (writing beyond the end of an array).

Also a red flag is that you are trying to maintain a vector and a pointer to it's data simultaneously. Obviously modifying the vector (by push_back for instance) can invalidate the pointer. I didn't see anything that made me think you'd got this wrong but since there's no benefit in doing it this way (just use an integer and call vector::data() when you need it) you might as well get rid.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing C++ standard library containers at library boundaries can be perilous and fragile.

The problem is that the library and its client are sharing a ill-defined binary interface in the storage layout of STL objects.  STL - by design - does not abstract much of its innards.  Doing so would seriously impact performance.

This can bite you when the library and its client (which, remember, share a common set of headers files) get compiled with different storage layouts.

Whilst this might change between compilers (or even compiler versions), the issue that really nasty gotcha is conditionally compiled code - and I suspect it's this that's causing your problem.

The STL implementation that ships with Visual Studio has traditionally enabled various forms of sanity checking - such as on iterator use - in debug builds which alter the storage layout of the compiled STL objects.

So, in summary, I suspect you have the client build as a debug release and the library in release mode (or vice versa).

Comment: There used to be another problem in that it was difficult to use STL containers across DLL boundaries because each DLL (and the main executable) maintained it's own heap. Or have Microsoft solved that problem now?

Comment: about the suspect i must say that all libraries are in debug build.
even i implement this class without using vectot and only with unsigned char *. but in this case i have problem with realloc with same exception.

Comment: exactly i got "Unhandled exception at 0x7743206e (ntdll.dll) in testDhcpv4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x8a60afa5." in the xmemory.h line 182.
(void deallocate(pointer _Ptr, size_type)
  { // deallocate object at _Ptr, ignore size
  ::operator delete(_Ptr);
  })

Comment: #jahhaj looks like this is still the case, and still a mine-field - and it's all down the rather strange property of DLLs in Windows having global private data (potentially shared between all users of the DLL) - and used to contain a heap.   

Doing a bit of reading around, many recommend using boost/tr/C++11 `shared_pointer` as an elegant solution as the object captures the creator's `operator delete` on construction, thus releasing to the correct heap.